# TFT Kernel module not loading on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, kernel

I'm not able to load a driver for a TFT display permanently on a Raspberry with Raspbian OS like specified here:

```
fbtft_device name=sainsmart18 verbose=0
```

in /etc/modules.

Whenever I restart the Raspberry and do

```
lsmod
```

the module is gone. However, setting it up manually with

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=sainsmart18
```

works perfectly. Does anyone know why?

**Output lsmod:**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              420690  0 
rfkill                 16659  2 cfg80211
8192cu                528485  0 
pl2303                  8340  0 
usbserial              22429  1 pl2303
snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s     6701  0 
regmap_mmio             2969  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_soc_core          132622  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_compress            7736  1 snd_soc_core
bcm2835_gpiomem         2995  0 
snd_pcm_dmaengine       3287  1 snd_soc_core
spi_bcm2835             7248  0 
i2c_bcm2708             5014  0 
joydev                  9047  0 
evdev                  10232  6 
uio_pdrv_genirq         2966  0 
uio                     8235  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 6047  0 
snd_bcm2835            19769  3 
snd_pcm                74825  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              18157  1 snd_pcm
snd                    52116  11 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_compress
fuse                   81710  3 
ipv6                  339514  32
```

**Output lsmod after sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=sainsmart18:**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fb_st7735r              3372  0 
fbtft_device           27517  0 
fbtft                  27628  2 fb_st7735r,fbtft_device
fb_sys_fops             1149  1 fbtft
syscopyarea             2789  1 fbtft
sysfillrect             3313  1 fbtft
sysimgblt               1837  1 fbtft
cfg80211              420690  0 
rfkill                 16659  2 cfg80211
pl2303                  8340  0 
8192cu                528485  0 
usbserial              22429  1 pl2303
snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s     6701  0 
regmap_mmio             2969  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_soc_core          132622  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_compress            7736  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine       3287  1 snd_soc_core
spi_bcm2835             7248  0 
i2c_bcm2708             5014  0 
bcm2835_gpiomem         2995  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         2966  0 
uio                     8235  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
joydev                  9047  0 
evdev                  10232  6 
i2c_dev                 6047  0 
snd_bcm2835            19769  3 
snd_pcm                74825  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              18157  1 snd_pcm
snd                    52116  11 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_compress
fuse                   81710  3 
ipv6                  339514  32
```

**Update:**

I did

```
dmesg
```

and there is an error:

```
 [    4.813718] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   [    4.847789] systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

I investigated further with

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
```

The output is

```
    systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-10-25 17:50:23 UTC; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 86 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 86 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Comment: Why do you use `name=sainsmart18` when you do the manual modprobe, and `name=adafruit22` when you add it to /etc/modules? What happens if you add `fbtft_device name=sainsmart18` to your `/etc/modules`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid typo. I'm using sainsmart18 also when I manually do `modprobe`. I have added `fbtft_device name=sainsmart18` to `/etc/modules`, but the module doesn't show up when I reboot and do `lsmod`. With `modprobe` the screen of the TFT also turns black, which is an indicator that it actually works. Screen stays white when I just add `fbtft_device name=sainsmart` in `/etc/modules`.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the driver is not blacklisted? Use `nano -w /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` to check. Can you also post the output of `lsmod` and `modprobe --list` ?

Comment: Blacklist is empty. Updated output from `lsmod`, but there is no `modprobe --list` ("unrecognized option '--list'). Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: How does lsmod look like after the manual 'modprobe' ?

Comment: Updated my original code.

Comment: On a hunch: can you add all the dependencies of `fbtft_device` and `fb_st7735r` to your `/etc/modules` and see if that makes a difference? And make sure none of those modules are blacklisted.

Comment: Didn't work. I found a hint though, see update.