# Sainsmart 1.8 inch tft not working

Tags: boot, pi-3, pitft

I am having the same problem as this
[TFT Kernel module not loading on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37611/tft-kernel-module-not-loading-on-startup?newreg=0bb18a27f80a496292e591714741a7be)

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank you